# A Star Wars thing, but what set is it from? A sphere with legs?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

A Star Wars thing but what set is it from?

[image: Star Wars sphere with legs]

Answer (score 1):

This is

[75142: Homing Spider Droid](https://brickset.com/sets/75142-1/Homing-Spider-Droid)

[image]

Keyparts

- [Dark Bluish Gray Brick, Round Corner 3 x 3 x 2 Dome Top](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=88293&colorID=85&in=A)
- D[ark Bluish Gray Projectile Launcher Part, Rapid Shooter Six Barrel - Angled Barrels](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=18588&colorID=85&in=A)